# How to select more fields with DISTINCT in JPA query?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

The JPA query below gives me perfect IDs that I want but I need the rest of the fields of that row.
I wonder if there is a another way to create this query where I can get all fields for these selected IDs.

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserResponseRepository extends JpaRepository<UserResponses, Integer> {
        
        @Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.users.userId,r.assessments.vassId FROM UserResponses r")
        List<Integer> findByAssessmentsUsers();
```

Table 1

```
    public class UserResponses implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer UrId;
        ...
        
        @ManyToOne
        private Users users;
            
        @ManyToOne
        private Assessments assessments;
```

Table 2

```
    public class Users implements Serializable {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer userId;
        ...
        
        @OneToMany
        private List<Assessments> assSet;
        
        @OneToMany
        private Set<UserResponses> userRes;
```

Table 3

```
    public class Assessments implements Serializable {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer vassId;
              
        @ManyToOne
        private Users users;
           
        @OneToMany
        private Set<UserResponses> userResSet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you need `group by` statement in your query instead of `distinct`

```
@Query("SELECT r.users.userId, r.assessments.vassId FROM UserResponses r group by r.users.userId, r.assessments.vassId")
List<Object[]> findByAssessmentsUsers();
```

But here query returns `List<Object[]>`. I'd recommend using  `List<AssessmentsDto>` as query result.

```
public class AssessmentsDto {
    public AssessmentsDto(Integer userId, Integer vassId) {
       this.userId = userId;
       this.vassId = vassId;
    }

    Integer userId;
    Integer vassId;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Integer getVassId() {
        return vassId;
    }
}
```

`Dto` usage:

```
@Query("SELECT new yourProject.dto.AssessmentsDto(r.users.userId, r.assessments.vassId) FROM UserResponses r group by r.users.userId, r.assessments.vassId")
    List<AssessmentsDto> findByAssessmentsUsers();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, assId was my typo here, it is vassId I've corrected it. I'll try your suggestion for the rest.

Comment: You've taught me something new here.